# how to do factory reset using ADB or an app

Tags: android

I want to do factory reset my device and also my device settings like allow app to install from unknown source and ADB should remain enable.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: You can also alter install from unknown source  setting by going in Setting--> Security ..

Comment: After `recovery --wipe_data` (suggested in the above link), the setting db will also be deleted. You MAY try to backup it and restore. But that needs root permission (writing to `/data/data/com.android.Settings`).

Answer (score -3):

Go to Setting --> Backup And Reset --> Reset your phone.

Comment: did not address "ADB should remain enable".

Comment: not satisfied answer....can anybody tell me how to to factory reset through ADB(my phone is not rooted)...plz suggest...